# How to define a command for printing a single biblatex entry?

Tags: biblatex

I want to define a command `\printentry` for printing a single biblatex entry with the same style and enumeration of the main bibliography.

My strategy so far has been to declare 100 bibliography categories entry0, entry1, ..., entry100 and define `\printentry` as follows:

```
\newcounter{prentry}
\newcommand{\printentry}[2][]{\nocite{#2}
    \addtocategory{entry\theprentry}{#2}
    \printbibliography[category=entry\theprentry,heading=none]
    \stepcounter{prentry}}
```

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\newcounter{int}
\makeatletter
\@whilenum\value{int}<100\do
{\expandafter\DeclareBibliographyCategory{entry\theint}\stepcounter{int}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{prentry}
\newcommand{\printentry}[2][]{\nocite{#2}
    \addtocategory{entry\theprentry}{#2}
    \printbibliography[category=entry\theprentry,heading=none]
    \stepcounter{prentry}}

\begin{document}

Text...

\printentry{lfba2020}

More text...

\printentry{lfba2019}

Even more text...

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

However, whereas `\theprentry` works in `\addtocategory`, it doesn't in `\printbibliography`. I know this because I have tested `\printentry` passing `entry0` in `\printbibliography`, and it printed `lfba2020` (in the desired form) for both `\printentry{lfba2020}` and `\printentry{lfba2019}`. (The same result is obtained when I replace `\theprentry` by `\arabic{prentry}`)

How can I modify this code to obtain the desired result? (Or what other approach should I take?)

Something else. As you can see, `\printentry` has an unused optional argument. I would like to use it, if possible, for changing the entry label (i.e. the shorthand that appears at the left of the entry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason `\printbibliography` `\detokenize`s the category name. So you need to expand the macro before you use it.

The following should work, but I couldn't test it for lack of a suitable `.bib` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\newcounter{int}
\makeatletter
\@whilenum\value{int}<100\do
{\expandafter\DeclareBibliographyCategory{entry\theint}\stepcounter{int}}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\printbibentry}[1]{\printbibliography[category=entry#1,heading=none]}

\newcounter{prentry}
\newcommand{\printentry}[2][]{\nocite{#2}%
  \addtocategory{entry\theprentry}{#2}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \printbibentry
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    {\theprentry}%
  \stepcounter{prentry}}

\begin{document}
Text...
\printentry{lfba2020}

More text...
\printentry{lfba2019}

Even more text...

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

Here's the solution I use to print only some entries with the normal `\printbibliography` setup in the `biblatex-ext` documentation.

The main idea is to use a bibcheck. We use the same bibcheck every time and only locally redefine the list the check tests against. That avoids polluting the name space for bibchecks or categories.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}


\makeatletter
\defbibcheck{examplebib}{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{entrykey}}{\extblxdoc@examplebib@list}
    {}
    {\skipentry}}

\newcommand*{\exampleprintbib}[1]{%
  \nocite{#1}%
  \let\extblxdoc@examplebib@list\empty
  \def\do##1{\listeadd\extblxdoc@examplebib@list{\detokenize{##1}}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}%
  \printbibliography[check=examplebib, heading=none]}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Text...
\exampleprintbib{sigfridsson}

More text...
\exampleprintbib{worman}

Even more text...

\nocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Three bibliographies]

Comment: For some reason, your second proposal worked whereas the first not. I'm, then, using the second. Thanks.

Comment: @lfba Oh right, the first attempt probably needs a few more `\expandafter`s. Added some. But I prefer the second solution anyway, so if you are using that now that would be the better outcome from my point of view..